# how to hide a column in gridview based on a condition?

Tags: asp.net, session, gridview

I have an action field in the gridview which comprises of two buttons. I want to hide action column depending upon condition that my session variable "role" != "admin". Means I want to hide the column if the session variable is not admin. Following is my code:-

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ButtonType="Button" title="Edit" CssClass="fa fa-edit btn btn-info btn-sm"
            Text="Edit"
            runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>' CommandName="Select" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CssClass="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger btn-sm" Text="Delete"
            Visible='<%# (Session["role"].ToString()=="admin"|| Session["role"].ToString()=="editor"||Session["role"].ToString()=="hotel")?true:false %>'
            runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide columns in code behind.

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin") == false)
{
    GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Or as one-liner.

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = !User.IsInRole("Admin");
```